# Android 10 API 29 (OS Error: Permission denied, errno = 13) to save file (Flutter)

Tags: android, flutter, android-permissions, android-10.0

I tried everything to avoid this problem but nothing. Interesting fact is that this problem is appears only on android 10(API 29) on 11 or < 10 works fine.
Here are my configurations:

build.gradle

```
compileSdkVersion 30
targetSdkVersion 30
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
                     android:maxSdkVersion="28" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">
```

debug/AndroidManifest.xml it's same. I tried to change target version to 29 and 28 but still nothing. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

android:maxSdkVersion="28"
try to remove this part

Comment: Yes, now it's works. No need anymore and this line of code <application android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true">. after API 28 WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE is not valid, right why did i have to remove it?

Comment: It is valid but you have to get permission from user.